# Adding Desired Capabilites/Capabilites in app.config in Selenium WebDriver on C#

Tags: c#, selenium, app-config, specflow, baseclass-contrib

At this moment writing tests for the project, using `Selenium` `WebDriver+SpecFlow+BaseClass.Contrib.Specflow.Selenium.NUnit` with C#.
At this moment looking for opportunity to add capabilities for the browsers through `app.config` file.

Can anyone show the example of working app.config with the capabilities?
Tried [this link](http://www.baseclass.ch/blog/Lists/Beitraege/Post.aspx?ID=5&mobile=0) but had an exception.

Thanks in advance,
Valentin.

Comment: After installing Nuget package in step 3, template for creating the feature seems missing in my VS2013.

Comment: Derloopkat, maybe you need to install SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio? Without it you will not see the .feature templates .

Comment: Now it says "unable to find the plugin search path...". Is that the error you're getting?

Comment: Can you show us the exception?

Comment: I tried this link only to write the capabilities, because the main project I already wrote, using other links. At this moment I can't reproduce the same exception, because the test fails without it. Maybe it was because capabilities word was written with small button. That is how it is at this moment:  http://s30.postimg.org/83qvmbvy9/img.png  I need add this capability to Firefox browser, so that Selenium doesn't had the Exception: Element is not clickable at point (x, y)....